# Very slow performing SQL case-expression (query optimization)

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I got this little code, which is actually alot longer, but i have created some temp work tables to speed up testing instead of running "with" all the time. The query runs okay the number of rows considered, untill the part showed below. I ahve made the two temp tables, "disc_memberlist" and billing_disc. I want to compare the two, and add a column which states if the user is present in billing_disc or not (The Y and N, in the case) If i specifi a pre determined agreement_id the select works fine. However if i remove it, and want it to go through all rows it grinds to a crawl. with 200 rows per 10 sec (and i need to parse a million)

Any suggestions to a way i could achieve this with better performance?

```
SELECT 
          dm.user_id
          ,dm.agreement_id
          ,dm.cust_id
          ,dm.offer_id
          ,dm.offer_type
          ,dm.resource_spec_id
          ,dm.memberlist_subscriber_count
          ,CASE
              WHEN dm.user_id in (SELECT user_id      
FROM   disc_memberlist dm
WHERE  dm.user_id IN (SELECT bd.resource_id
                          FROM  billing_disc bd )) 
                  THEN
             'Y'
             ELSE
             'N'
      END AS Exists_in_billing
```

The execution plan is

```
"PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"
"Plan hash value: 3054186447"
" "
"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"| Id  | Operation          | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |"
"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                           |  1727K|    87M|    21G  (1)|232:59:10 |"
"|*  1 |  HASH JOIN SEMI    |                           |     1 |    18 | 12480   (1)| 00:00:01 |"
"|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| AGREEMENT_MEMBERLIST_KRPS |     1 |     9 |  3896   (1)| 00:00:01 |"
"|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| BILLING_DISC_KRPS         |    30 |   270 |  8585   (1)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   4 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL | AGREEMENT_MEMBERLIST_KRPS |  1727K|    87M|  3899   (1)| 00:00:01 |"
"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
" "
"Predicate Information (identified by operation id):"
"---------------------------------------------------"
" "
"   1 - access(""DM"".""USER_ID""=""BD"".""RESOURCE_ID"")"
"   2 - filter(""USER_ID""=:B1)"
"   3 - filter(""BD"".""RESOURCE_ID""=:B1)"
```

Comment: Can you share the execution plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `IN`. If you have correct indexes on the columns `disc_memberlist.user_id` and `billing_disc.resource_id` it should improve performances as it would not do a full scan in your table.

```
SELECT 
    dm.user_id
    ,dm.agreement_id
    ,dm.cust_id
    ,dm.offer_id
    ,dm.offer_type
    ,dm.resource_spec_id
    ,dm.memberlist_subscriber_count
    ,NVL2(bd.resource_id, 'Y', 'N') AS Exists_in_billing
FROM disc_memberlist dm
LEFT JOIN billing_disc bd ON dm.user_id = bd.resource_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a temporary table with the three tables (`LEFT JOIN`). Do not forget to index and create the correct variables using `procedure analyse`. Also try to `EXPLAIN` query, it will give you more hints on how to improve performance.